# How to avoid CHROME prefetch request at OAUTH flow?

Tags: .net, google-chrome, iis, oauth, prefetch

I talk about .NET & IIS.

When type protected resource URL - it starts all OAUTH proccess (getting auth code, and even getting access tokens).

It seems to me - CHROME caches prefetch results, even redirect results. So, when real request begins execute - it got expired auth-code and falls with error.

I try to catch such prefetch requests and cancel it at server side, but it leads to side effects - real requests cancel too.

Comment: Use developer tools or Fiddler to confirm. The more you know about the issue itself, the clearer what measures to take.

Comment: What kind of issue are you talking about? Prefetch request simply grab auth-code and... Cache it?

Comment: and prefetch requests passing by developers tools.

Comment: about confirm - there is a special header in request purpose:prefetch